# After a desire ouput Not able to print date from both date/time

Tags: python

Hello Experts i have a program that read the csv file which contain several columns main motive of this program is to convert the string into seuence of number and duplicated string will be the same number which have taken this all operation i can able to perform but I want my *date/time column* to print only date for that i applied a slicing method that's work in console but I'm not able to to print it on my other csv file. Please tell me what to do.

This is the program I have written:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os 
# from io import StringIO
# tempFile="input1.csv"

with open("input1.csv", 'r',encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # next(reader, None)

    '''We then restructure the data to be a set of keys with list of values {key_1: [], key_2: []}:'''        
    data = {}
    for row in reader:
        # print(row)
        for header, value in row.items():
            try:
                data[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                data[header] = [value]

    '''Next we want to give each value in each list a unique identifier.'''            
    # Loop through all keys
    for key in data.keys():
        values = data[key]

        things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

        for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):

            if key=="Date/Time":
                var = data[key]
                iter_obj1 = iter(var)
                while True:
                    try:
                        element1 = next(iter_obj1)
                        date =element1[0:10]
                        print("date-",date)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
                break
            else:
                # if key == "Date/Time" :
                #     print(x[0:10])
                #     continue
                data[key][i] = things.index(x) + 1
                print('data.[keys]()-',data[key])
                print('data.keys()-',data.keys())
                print('values-',values)
                print('data.keys()-',key)
                print('x-',x)
                print('i-',i)

        # print("FullName-",FullName)

"""Since csv.writerows() takes a list but treats it as a row, we need to restructure our 
    data so that each row is one value from each list. This can be accomplished using zip():"""

with open("ram3.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    # Write headers
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    # Make one row equal to one value from each list
    rows = zip(*data.values())
    # Write rows
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Note: I can't use pandas `DataFrame`. That's why I have written code like this please tell me how to print my date/time column only date where i need to change in code to get that...thanks

**Input:**

```
job_Id      Name        Address     Email           Date/Time
1       snehil singh    marathalli  ss@gmail.com    12/10/2011:02:03:20
2       salman          marathalli  ss@gmail.com    12/11/2011:03:10:20
3       Amir            HSR         ar@gmail.com    11/02/2009:09:03:20
4       Rakhesh         HSR         rakesh@gmail.com    09/12/2010:02:03:55
5       Ram             marathalli  r@gmail.com     01/10/2014:12:03:20
6       Shyam           BTM         ss@gmail.com    12/11/2012:01:03:20
7       salman          HSR         ss@gmail.com    11/08/2016:15:03:20
8       Amir            BTM         ar@gmail.com    07/10/2013:04:02:30
9       snehil singh    Majestic    sne@gmail.com   03/03/2018:02:03:20
```

**Csv file:**

```
job_Id  Name    Address Email   Date/Time

     1     1    1          1    12/10/2011:02:03:20

     2     2    1          1    12/11/2011:03:10:20

     3     3    2          2    11/02/2009:09:03:20

     4     4    2          3    09/12/2010:02:03:55

     5     5    1          4    01/10/2014:12:03:20

     6     6    3          1    12/11/2012:01:03:20

     7     2    2          1    11/08/2016:15:03:20

     8     3    3          2    07/10/2013:04:02:30

     9     1    4          5    03/03/2018:02:03:20
```

In this output, everything is correct but only the date/time column. I want to print date only, and not time.

Comment: You can convert the date/time strings to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects, and while writing to the file, get whatever format of the date that you want.

Comment: i got it.. thnx

Comment: i have doubt that if we have a date/time column in which some of the columns are empty then i want to replace that empty cell with todays date how it will work the same code i have written above please help with this.......

Answer (score 0):

```
if key=="Date/Time":
                 var="12/10/2011"
                 print(var) 
                 var = data[key]
                 iter_obj1 = iter(var)
                 while True:
                    try:
                         element1 = next(iter_obj1)
                         date =element1[0:10]
                         print("date-",date)
                     except StopIteration:
                         break
```

i got it i should not use all these...things just added one line will print the desired output in the for loop..

```
if key=="Date/Time":
   data[key][i] = data[key][i][0:10]
```

that's it.. its done all will be same..